# TensorFlow2 alternative to tf.io.gfile.Open()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to work through [Machine Learning with Apache Beam and TensorFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/samples/molecules-walkthrough) but with TF2. The (Python) source is all TF1 and I'm playing whackamole  with the TF1 functions. This one has me blocked: `with tf.io.gfile.Open(sdf_file, 'w')` TF2 `tf.io.gfile` has no `Open`

In the example code all this is doing is reading a file downloaded from PubChem. PubChem files can be other than SDF so that's not a deal breaker, but I'd like to stay as close as possible to the source in the Apache Beam and TensorFlow example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have seen in the official documentation of TF2 model garden example :  `with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid: encoded_jpg = fid.read()` . Please refer this link [https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html]